# How to Combine Frequency and Percentage in 1 Cell in SPSS with Frequency displayed in bracket

Tags: data-analysis, analysis, spss, spss-modeler

Tried making them show together in one cell by going to analyze, crosstabulations, clicking cells and percentage on rows but it's always brought out in separate rows like this

[image]

I need to merge them in one cell for each row so the frequency and percentage appears side by side separated by brackets.

Comment: Maybe possible to do in the output with Custom Tables module (don't have it myself so can't help you) but you can create this in your dataset if you want to (a bit of a longish process) - let me know if you want to try.